# How to restrict direct access from internet to Azure Public LoadBalancer backend pool VM with NSG

Tags: azure-load-balancer, network-security-groups

As the question at title, I'm setup the following architecture on Azure Cloud and having trouble at restricting direct access from the internet to VMs.

[image]

**Here are architecture requirements:**

- Both VMs must have public ips (for SysAdmin to access via SSH)
- Direct traffics from Internet to WebService on VMs (via port 80) must be denied
- The web traffics from Internet must go thru Public LB to VMs

Suppose that both VMs are in WebASG (Application Security Group), in the NSG setting that applied to VM's Subnet, I've add some rules (which have higher priority than 3 Azure NSG default rules):

1. Scenario A (adding 1 custom rule):

> Port: **80** - Protocol: **Tcp** - Source: **Internet** - Destination:
>   **WebASG** - Action: **Allow**

With this NSG setting, I could access WebService from LoadBalancer IP (satisfy #3 requirement), but WebService on port 80 of both VMs will be exposed to Internet (that violates #2 requirement)

2. Scenario B (adding 2 custom rules):

> Port: **80** - Protocol: **Tcp** - Source: **AzureLoadBalancer** -
>   Destination: **WebASG** - Action: **Allow**
>
> Port: **80** - Protocol: **Tcp** - Source: **Internet** - Destination:
>   **WebASG** - Action: **Deny**

With this NSG setting, #2 requirement is satisfied, but I could not access WebService when visit LoadBalancer IP (violates #3 requirement)

**Please note that:** using  AGW (Azure Application Gateway, I could make all the requirements happened by these NSG configuration:

> RuleName: **AllowSSH** Port: **22** - Protocol: **Tcp** - Source:
>   **sys-admin-ip-address** - Destination: **WebASG** - Action: **Allow**
>
> RuleName: **DenyInternet2Web** Port: **Any** - Protocol: **Any** -
>   Source: **Internet** - Destination: **WebASG** - Action: **Deny**
>
> RuleName: **AllowProbe2Web** Port: **80** - Protocol: **Tcp** -
>   Source: **VirtualNetwork** - Destination: **WebASG** - Action:
>   **Allow**
>
> RuleName: **AllowProbe2Web** Port: **80** - Protocol: **Tcp** -
>   Source: **VirtualNetwork** - Destination: **WebASG** - Action:
>   **Allow**

I dont want using AGW because it would cost more money than Azure LoadBalancer (actually the Basic LoadBalancer is free). So, how could I change NSG to satisfy all requirements when using LoadBalancer?

**Thank in advance for any help!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there are NSG rules that will satisfy all requirements because of the #1 and #2 requirements are contradictory.

If the VMs must have public IP addresses, it actually has a chance to expose to the Internet. Any clients could access the VMs via the public IP. It works the same if you want to access the VMs through the load balancer frontend IP. Read the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-overview#load-balancer-concepts

> Load Balancer doesn't terminate or originate flows, interact with the
>   payload of the flow, or provide any application layer gateway
>   function. Protocol handshakes always occur directly between the client
>   and the back-end pool instance. A response to an inbound flow is
>   always a response from a virtual machine. When the flow arrives on the
>   virtual machine, the original source IP address is also preserved.

In this case, you could remove the backend-instance IP address, just use the load balancer frontend for the web traffic and SSH connection. If so, You could [configure port forwarding in Azure Load Balancer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/tutorial-load-balancer-port-forwarding-portal) for the SSH connections to individual instances and a load balancer rule for the web traffic following this [quickstart](http://Quickstart), which works with standard LB. You can only allow port 80 and 22 from your clients' IP addresses. The NSG will look like this,

**Port**: 80,22 - **Protocol**: Tcp - **Source**: client's IP list - **Destination**: WebASG - **Action**: Allow

Comment: Thank for your time. I've updated the post to show how all the requirements happened with Azure Application Gateway. In my mind, ApplicationGateway and LoadBalancer must work in the same way (in a manner that they both stand at front-end, accept client requests, forward to backend VMs, get response, then return response to client... so they would hide their backend VMs from client)

Comment: no, APP GW and LB does not work in the same way. App GW works at the Application Layer ( Layer 7) while LB works at Transport Layer ( Layer 4). NSG rules are evaluated by priority using the 5-tuple information (source, source port, destination, destination port, and protocol) to allow or deny the traffic. LB uses a hashing algorithm for the distribution of inbound flows and rewrites the headers of flows to backend pool instances.

Comment: When NSG works on the web traffic, For an LB flow, it doesn't terminate or originate flows, interact with the payload of the flow, or provide any application layer gateway function. Protocol handshakes always occur directly between the client and the back-end pool instance. but APP GW traffic, It acts as a reverse proxy service. This terminates the client connection and forwards request to back endpoints. Refer to [the difference](https://adityaswami89.wordpress.com/2016/12/21/difference-between-azure-balancer-application-gateway-and-traffic-manager/)

Comment: I know that AGW operates at Layer 7 and LB does at Layer 4, but in my user-case of using LB, I only need one feature: hide VMs backend behind LB. With LB, I agree that protocol handshakes always occur directly between the client and the back-end pool instance, but it does not mean the client is redirected to the backend VM's IP. As this [doc](https://www.nginx.com/resources/glossary/layer-4-load-balancing/), LB alway stands between Client and Backend VM pool to forward packet, LB only edit the source/destination IP in packet (so, that why "For an LB flow, it doesn't terminate or originate...".

Comment: `but it does not mean the client is redirected to the backend VM's IP. ` Yes, I agree. for example, client1 send a request to backend via LB front IP, it will generate a flow `source client1, source port, protocol, destination LB IP, destination port`. When hitting the load balancer, with Inbound NAT rules, it will change to `source client1, source port, protocol, destination VM IP, dest port` but the source IP for incoming traffic does not change, the NSG rule still is evaluated with the *same source IP* in the inbound rules. with LB or not, it will work the same for a client for NSG rules.